# Limit the text when i share my site link on facebook

Tags: facebook, wordpress

When i paste my site url on facebook it show very different content.[image]

Here is the screenshot. Now i want when i share the link it show the site logo instead of posts images and the site description. Is there any solution of this. My site is in wordpress.

Comment: I am not positive by just using a wordpress plugin. However using a metatage in you header for the page you can direct facebook what to show. like so `<meta property="og:image" content="LINK TO YOUR IMAGE HERE">`

Comment: Open Graph meta tags on your site are not correct ([link to Open Graph debugger's output](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Ftripgoggles.com%2F)), please fix these issues, maybe then you could fix issues with your site

Comment: @brendanmorrison i already useing the `meta`, But it still not working

Comment: @AnveshSaxena Thanks it work great but logo still missing.

Comment: Please check again as it seems you have duplicated open graph meta tags twice. Please have only one set of these.